# Export very wide (more than 1600 column) queries to CSV

Tags: java, postgresql

In my current project, we have many small-ish tables stored in a postgres database.  The most common operation is to export a CSV file, which is a selection of columns from some/all of the tables joined on a common key.  Each column can be of any datatype, as it is determined by what the user inputs into the system.

I achieve the result by creating a table that is X columns wide, then copy the data into it, where X is the number of columns selected by the user.

My problem is that the user often wants to export thousands of columns.  I've quickly hit the maximum table that postgres will allow me to create, which is 1600.  From what I understand, this is limited by the page size, and number of columns/the memory size of each column.  I could just increase the page size, but I'm ultimately going to keep hitting this limit.

My new solution is break the export down across multiple tables, where each table gets written to its own csv file.  The key column will be in all files, so some other program could index and link the data potentially.

My question is, how do I determine how much space each column will take up?  Does each datatype take up a linear amount of memory?  Is there any padding I need to take into consideration?

Comment: The users request 1600 columns? That sounds like something is not represented correctly. It's usually the number of rows which is large. What scenario requires so many columns?

Comment: The data is research data.  Each row is a subject, each column a measured variable.  Each small table is a dataset taken at a given time.  The users have a very 'simple' approach, and essentially want to view all variables for all subjects, or subsets of those variables, such as 'all variables which are the result of a certain type of test (this still equates to a few thousand)'.

Comment: Realistically I'd like to just export one subject at a time, that way I can export a 2 column key-pair style table, but the users won't settle for anything less than a very tabular export, so I'd be doing thousands of single export tables, then having to format them on the client side, which I can't imagine being performant.

Comment: Well, the tables in database should be in the key-value structure (dataset-variable-value per row), You should do the *tabulation* part programatically.

Comment: This would be very expensive to implement at the stage.  It would also be very unperformant.

Comment: Maybe it's expensive to change the database, but as for performance - that's how it's done. Reporting programs do pivot tables like that all the time. It's especially easy if your output is a CSV, as you can just write the data as it comes in. Linking and indexing outside of the database is going to be where you'll lose performance.

Comment: While very wide tables are generally a bad design, this is a case where it seems quite reasonable. Have you tried bypassing the creation of the table? Instead of `CREATE TABLE temptable AS SELECT ...` then `COPY ... FROM temptable;`, try `\COPY (SELECT ...) ...`. I don't *think* the 1600 column limit applies to queries. *Edit*: Nope, tested, and `ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries`. Pretty fundamental limitation here. Consider using an ETL tool for the export, like Pentaho Kettle, Talend Studio, etc, if you need the very wide results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't even `\copy (SELECT ...)` a row wider than 1664 columns:

```
ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries
```

so you're going to have to find a different way to do this.

Increasing PostgreSQL's page size will kick the problem down the road a bit, but won't solve your problem, just delay it, and create numerous other problems in the process. Non-default block sizes aren't tested much, may not perform as well, and are a pain when doing PITR / backup and restore / `pg_upgrade` etc.

Consider using an ETL tool like Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle or CloverETL to handle the export and join the data up.

---

> My question is, how do I determine how much space each column will take up?

Use `pg_column_size`. Note that some types can be stored compressed and out-of-line, per the [TOAST documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html), so `pg_column_size(somecol)` and `pg_column_size('text_of_somecol')` are *not the same thing*. Additionally, `pg_column_size` doesn't report the width of the toast pointer for TOAST-able types stored out-of-line, it reports the stored size. So for TOASTable (variable length) types you have to work it out yourself based on the documented size:

> Allowing for the varlena header bytes, the total size of a TOAST pointer datum is therefore 18 bytes regardless of the actual size of the represented value.

The primitive types are simple fixed width types. float4, float8, int4, int8, bool, `"char"` (which is *not the same thing* as `char` or `character`, the quotes are significant), etc.

Anything that stores text or text-like data is variable width. `text`, `varchar`, `bytea`, etc, are all toastable.

You can learn specifics by querying the `pg_type` catalog. See the documentation for the meaning of the fields.

> Does each datatype take up a linear amount of memory?

As noted above, it depends on the type.

> Is there any padding I need to take into consideration?

Yes. It's type-specific and relates to memory alignment requirements. See the `pg_type` catalog for alignment information.

`pg_column_size` on the whole row, e.g. `select pg_column_size(x) FROM mytable` can be informative.

For the gorey details see the comments on `src/backend/access/common/heaptuple.c`.